# Getting s TS2503 when trying to use an imported string constant to constrain a typescript type literal

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn redux by following some examples from the internet, but I'm running into a TypeScript error that I don't know how to fix...

I have two files in the same directory... **constants.ts** and **types.ts**.

**constants.ts** exports an Actions constant containing string values:

```
// constants.ts
export const Actions = {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  TOGGLE: 'TOGGLE',
};
```

**types.ts** contains an ActionType which will be used to specify the parameter type in my Redux reducer functions... it uses the Actions constant and looks like:

```
// types.ts
import { Actions } from "./constants";

export type ActionType = {
  cmd: Actions.ADD | Actions.TOGGLE,
  data: any
};
```

I am trying to define the ActionType.cmd property so that it can only be either 'ADD' or 'TOGGLE'...

If I write these values directly, ex:

```
cmd: 'ADD' | 'TOGGLE'
```

everything works fine... but when I try to use the string values defined in my Actions constant, I get a **TS2503** error, saying **'Cannot find namespace Actions'**.

Is this possible, or am I missing something?  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've defined `Actions` as a constant, `Actions.ADD` is only available as a value, not as a type.  Consider using an enum instead:

```
export enum Actions {
  ADD = 'ADD',
  TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE',
};

export type ActionType = {
  cmd: Actions,  // short for Actions.ADD | Actions.TOGGLE
  data: any
};
```

The members of an enum are available as both values and literal types.

Comment: Thanks... I wasn't sure if it was accepted convention to use enums for action types in redux, but after doing some digging it seems that string enums are considered OK, so I will change these to match your example...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you can't use the value of `Actions.ADD` directly as a type.

You can use `typeof` to get the type of a value, and `keyof` to get the keys, so the following works if the names and values of the keys are the same.

```
type ActionType = {
  cmd: keyof typeof Actions,
  data: any
};
```

Comment: Thanks... This is good to know, but I decided to go with string enums instead, as it seems a little cleaner... but will definitely keep this in mind for future use...